# Search and highlight in gtksource.view?

Tags: python, search, gtk3, gtksourceview

Gedit uses search highlighting. I'm aware that Gedit uses gtksourceview, and am wondering how that searching mechanism is accomplished.

Comment: Why not look at the Gedit source code? git.gnome.org/browse/gedit

Comment: Tried it and I still don't know. I'll be looking at it some more. If I figure out something I'll try to remember to post back here if no one else answers. The code in there is pretty so that makes it nice. :)

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I'll try to find the time to post an answer. Since it's a python app I was able to do regex too. For now I'll say it has something to do with using a python regex iterable and using the integers from that to define a location for Gtk.TextIter. I never did really take a good look at the Gedit code. Maybe in time I will. :)